# Give options at the end of command

Tags: macos, command-line, open-source

Let's say I want to copy a directory A to B, I should execute this command `cp -r A B` but for some reason I forgot to give it the `-r` flag. Comming from Linux I usually do `!! -r` but this is not a valid option in Mac.

```
~/tmp ❯ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
~/tmp ❯ cp A B
cp: A is a directory (not copied).
~/tmp ❯ !! -r
~/tmp ❯ cp A B -r
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

Is this the difference between BSD and GNU? Is it possible to give options at the end of the command on Mac? I'm using Zsh in both Linux and MacOS

Comment: AFAIK the `!!` is a ZSH feature. So are you using ZSH on Linux but Bash on macOS? You can find out simply via `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: This is a feature of the shell - which one are you using in Linux and in macOS and what is youe environment whenyou try the !! command

Comment: !! is in bash https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators 9well at least in current bash - I can't remeber if macOS old bash has it)

Comment: `bash` does.  And it's a configurable option in `ksh`.  Dunno if it's on by default in `zsh` or if it's something you have to enable.  But options after arguments are not valid in BSD.

Comment: I'm using Zsh in both Mac and Linux via Alacritty

Comment: Looking at the _manual page_ for `cp` in both **macOS** and **Linux** it shows the _options_ come directly after `cp`.

Comment: @user3439894 The GNU versions accept them also at the end (unless the order relevant, of course)

Comment: @nohillside, I was merely pointing out that the documentation shows the same, regardless of what can actually be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default commands on macOS don‘t accept options at the end, so `!! -r` won‘t work. You can install the GNU versions via Homebrew.

PS: You could also type `^cp^cp -r^`, but that's rather cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you, I manage to install most of the GNU command line tools flavor I need following this https://gist.github.com/skyzyx/3438280b18e4f7c490db8a2a2ca0b9da